# C# Visual Studio Truncating String parameter in INSERT query

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, query-builder

I've tried to search for an answer but have had no luck.
I'm trying to insert a large String into an Microsoft Access "memo" field. Most people seem to encounter an issue where the database truncates their String to 255 characters. That is not my issue.

I'm trying to do a simple INSERT using the following command:

```
INSERT INTO Images
(Code, Issue, FileName)
VALUES        (?, ?, ?)
```

I'm using the Table Adapter Query Configuration Wizard to do this. E.g, call the query using the table adapter as below

```
TableAdapter Adapter = new TableAdapter();
Adapter.InsertCode(Code, Issue, FileName);
```

However after I complete the INSERT, I check the file in the database and find that it has been truncated to around 1000 characters. Strangely enough, this only occurs when I run the query programmatically. If I use the query builder while configuring the query and manually insert the values, everything works fine.

I've tried writing the String to a file, and it looks fine. It's only somewhere during the INSERT that the String is truncated.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution.
I'm guessing that because I used the DataSet.xsd file that provides a visual display of the Database and allows for creation of queries using the query builder, Visual Studio performs a lot work in the background.

When I clicked on the query under the Table Adapter and viewed the properties, then clicked on the parameter settings, the max size for the String parameters was 1024 characters. I simply changed this value.

Hope I manage to help anyone else that comes across this issue.